# best practice to know how may threads are running

Tags: java, spring-boot, executorservice

I have a SOAP Services environement implemented using SpringBoot 1.5.8 & Java 8 that do some stuff, some of that are parallelized via ExecutorService for each request. The information that we need is the number of active thred of a specific class (ie MyCallable). All stuff are embedded in a Callable right now, so what I've tought about issomething like that but, I don't know what, but there is something bad in my implementation that tell me "you do it in the wrong way"

```
public class MyCallable implements Callable<?>{

    public static final AtomicInteger THREAD_COUNT = new AtomicInteger();
    
    @Override
    public byte[] call() throws RichException {
        THREAD_COUNT.incrementAndGet();
        try{
           ...
        }catch(...){
           ...
        }finally{
            MyCallable.THREAD_COUNT.decrementAndGet();
        } 
    }
}

@Component
public class ScheduledTasks {
    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void reportCurrentTime() {
        log.info("Thread count: {}", MyCallable.THREAD_COUNT.get());
    }
}
```

someone can help to troubleshoot this ?

Comment: I have not get your idea. Could you give more details about why you needto know the number of active thread on specific class?

Comment: @shanfeng 'couse MyCallable is just a call to another WS that sometime suffer a lot, so a kpi that we need to know is if is our system that stress it and,  if it is, how ! right now is a information that we dont have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a monitoring infrastructure present in your system, like Prometheus, you should definitely take a look at Micrometer and using Counter meter for this purpose.

Micrometer is shipped with [Spring Actuator](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/actuator.html)

But, on the topic: Make `AtomicInteger` `private`, so only your implementation can change the value.

Add `public static int get()` method, which will delegate to `THREAD_COUNT.get()`